# How to model this particular table relationship

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, entity-relationship

I want to create data model for the below scenario. I have a table called PERSON and HEALTH_STANDARDS.

PERSON has id,name,address,email
HEALTH_STANDARDS has weight,height etc.,

In UI , if the user select a person and it has to show the standard health attributes . Next, user will change the health attributes according to the selected person.
Rest of the persons will have the standard health attributes.

How can I model this . Do I need to create one more table PERSON_HEALTH_ATTRIBUTES and do the mapping here.

Comment: Why not just save each persons health attributes as columns in the person table?

Comment: Yeah sounds like PERSON could have a `health_standard_id` record, which references the HEALTH_STANDARDS `id`.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: @jarlh ..I am using Postgres.

Comment: Personally I would use individual tables for `PERSON_WEIGHT`, `PERSON_STANDARD_WEIGHT`, `PERSON_HEIGHT`, `PERSON_STANDARD_HEIGHT`, etc

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that `HEALTH_STANDARDS` are constants/defaults that don't actually correspond to an actual person, therefore there is no direct relationship between `PERSON` and `HEALTH_STANDARDS`. Rather it can be implied when a given person has no row in `PERSON_HEALTH_ATTRIBUTES` i.e. it defaults to the standard value e.g. restricting the attributes to just weight for simplicity:

```
CREATE TABLE HEALTH_STANDARDS
( person_weight_kg INTEGER NOT NULL );

CREATE TABLE PERSON
( person_id INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  name VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL );

CREATE TABLE PERSON_HEALTH_ATTRIBUTES 
( person_id INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE
     REFERENCES PERSON ( person_id ),
  person_weight_kg INTEGER NOT NULL );


SELECT person_id, person_weight_kg
  FROM PERSON_HEALTH_ATTRIBUTES
UNION
SELECT person_id, person_weight_kg
  FROM PERSON
       NATURAL JOIN HEALTH_STANDARDS
 WHERE person_id NOT IN ( SELECT person_id
                            FROM PERSON_HEALTH_ATTRIBUTES );
```

Answer (score 0):

Because there is a one-to-one relation with PERSON and their HEALTH attributes, you should just combine them into 1 table. If there is only 1 default value for the default HEALTH_STANDARDS, I would just implement that as default values on the PERSON table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should design the table structure like bellow described in a image.

where a person has one to many relation with health standard as person can have many heath standards like height , weight , colour. so we should create one more table which will contain the person heath standards data here we have created **person_health_standard** table

health_standard is a master data

[image]